# Field updates that are executed as approval actions don't trigger process

Tags: approval-process, process-builder, field-update

I am updating a checkbox field "Is approved" when a record is approved by approval process.

When this field is updated I want to trigger an action that create account record.
However this is not working.

When I logged case with salesforce they are saying

**Field updates that are executed as approval actions don't trigger workflow rules**

I have also tried **Re-evaluate Workflow Rules** but it is also not working.

what is the work around for this? If I don't want to use trigger.

Comment: Have you tried setting "Re-evaluate Workflow Rules" After Field Change checkbox on the Field Update?

Comment: related: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputHidden.htm?search_text=inputHidden

Answer (score 1):

For your case, Best option is to use the Process Builder

1) Create one Picklist value with "Approved", "Rejected" and "In Process". Put the "In Process" as Default value.

2) Now use "Field Update" in the Approval Process i.e. For Approval, the Field update must be "Approved" and For Rejection, the Field update must be "Rejected".

**Note: "Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change" checkbox must be checked in both "field update" Actions**

3) In Process Builder, Create an Object where you are Submitting for Approval.

4) Now In the "Add Criteria" node, put the condition as If the PickList Value is equal to "In Process" and Save the Criteria.

5) Now add the Immediate actions for "Submit for Approval" and Choose "Specific Approval Process in the Option and Give the Name of the Approval Process that you have Created. Save this Action.

6) Create another Action but this time choose,"Create a Record". You can Create any record here in this immediate Action of "Create a Record".

7)  Check for the Validation Rules existed in the Object and Give the values for the fields according to those validation rules

8) Now, Save the Immediate actions and Activate the Process Builder.

Comment: I have tried the "Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change" option it is not working.
Also, as per our business requirement, we need to submit record for approval manually not through process builder.

Comment: Then you have to write a trigger for creating a record.
Is the "update field" actions working in approval process?
Once uncheck the "Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change" checkbox in any one of Approval Field Update or else Rejection Field Update and do vice-versa for both field updates...

Answer (score 1):

On your Field Update, check the box that says "Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change".

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063000000047khAAA

Answer (score 0):

As of Spring '22, you can trigger Record-Change Triggered Flows on a field updated by an approval process. Note that if you have an existing Record-triggered flow that was created before Spring '22, you need to resave it using the Spring '22 'API Version' of 54 (or higher) in order to have it trigger this way. (See https://drive.google.com/file/d/178CjjDB5obFdVQnKBTwZQSO64gnFZcz2/view?usp=sharing) Salesforce did this so that existing flows wouldn't suddenly start triggering unexpectedly.