# does a flow get triggered when a record gets updated by an approval process in salesforce?

Tags: visual-workflow, approval-process

The flow (record triggered) should run when a check box is made true on update. It runs when the check box is checked manually on an update and saved. But It also should run when the check box is checked by an approval process - but this doesn't seem to work.

I am stuck! Process builder can launch a flow only when a manual update happens. It cannot launch a flow when an approval process updates a record, which is what I want. This is what I found out from my tests.

This is basically what my flow does: https://youtu.be/RZOClRIpZeg

Since I couldn't get this flow to fire from an approval process, because I needed this flow to run when the status is Approved, I hoped I could do it using process builder, since PB can launch a flow.

So I did a save as and duplicated the flow to an auto launched flow with no trigger so it could be called in from the Process Builder and supplied the required ids but PB did not launch the flow when the approval process updated the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approval process cannot trigger a flow. But Process builder can trigger an auto launched (no trigger) flow. Record triggered flow cannot be triggered from PB.

"Re-evaluate Workflow Rules After Field Change" option must be checked.

This has been confirmed with Salesforce Support.

Answer (score 2):

Seems this issue is a [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V0000003xVKQAY) in Salesforce. Currently this issue in review condition and doesn't get any fix from Salesforce side.

So please call your flow by using Process Builder based on this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/102887/field-updates-that-are-executed-as-approval-actions-dont-trigger-process)'s answer.

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Called the flow using Process Builder. It works if you manually update the record, but when again an approval process updates the record, the flow is not getting triggered even from Process Builder...

Comment: Nope, process builder need to triggered based on that field update (updated by approval process). Then the triggered process builder need to call your flow to complete further actions. That I mean in above answer.

Comment: Question is, will Process Builder trigger a flow when an approval process updates a record?

Comment: In your approval process - field update action, you need to enable "Re-evaluate Workflow Rules After Field Change" option. then once field updated this will trigger the process builder or  workflow rules which are run based on that field change. So that's why I asking to try to create a process builder based on that field update. then you can call your flow via that triggered process builder.

Comment: Yes, Re-evaluate Workflow Rules is checked. Doesn't make a difference. The flow is triggering from Process Builder when the record is manually updated. But the flow is not triggering when an approval process updates a record.

Comment: So you're saying, even that option "Re-evaluate Workflow Rules After Field Change" enabled condition also it's not triggered any process builder which is triggered based on that field change?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130463/discussion-between-mohanraj-and-rt12sf).

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed as of the Spring '22 version. Note that if you have an existing Record-triggered flow that was created before Spring '22, you need to resave it using the Spring '22 'API Version' of 54 (or higher) in order to have it trigger this way. (See https://drive.google.com/file/d/178CjjDB5obFdVQnKBTwZQSO64gnFZcz2/view?usp=sharing) Salesforce did this so that existing flows wouldn't suddenly start triggering unexpectedly.